# How to apply permanent redirect in Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-server-components

In Next JS 12 if you want to redirect you used to return an object from getServerSideProps that holds the distination path and if it is a permanent redirect or not

```
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: "/",
      permanent : true
    },
  };
```

now in Next js 13 we should use redirect() in server components but this redirect() function  does not accept any parameters other than the destination
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect

Comment: Is this permanent redirection known or its depends on some logic?

Comment: it depends on some logic. so I can not add it to next config file